# Same Origin Policy in intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk

I know this is a simple question, but do Intel XDK apps enforce the same origin policy? That is, can I make an ajax request to an arbitrary website? Is there some setting I have to enable to permit this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to make ajax requests to a foreign website within Intel XDK or apps built by XDK, I recommend that you add the ***xhr.js*** script in the HEAD element.

For example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
        *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
        input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
        body { background-color:white; color:black }
    </style>
    <script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
    <script src='xhr.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Intel native bridge is available */
        var onDeviceReady=function(){
        //hide splash screen
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        };
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- content goes here-->
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

For more information about making ajax requests within Intel XDK, go to https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/how-to-access-JSON-data-in-HTML5-apps

Comment: What exactly does xhr.js do?

Comment: The _xhr.js_ script allow you to make Cross Origin Requests (in other words, perform GET/POST request to external websites or web APIs).